# XPATH : Extract data from Soap Message

Tags: xml, xpath

I have got the following soap message and would like to know how to write xpath query to extract the GetNewGUIDResult?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="06996737-224f-4004-9dad-042222b161fc" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">b89cdee8-18b4-4ea0-a5a1-7b10ace1b23e</ActivityId>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<GetNewGUIDResponse xmlns="http://bank.co.com/Service/2011_01/Service">
<GetNewGUIDResult>125959</GetNewGUIDResult>
</GetNewGUIDResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I tried some some xpath commands but they are giving exceptions. Also I am not sure about the usage of xmlnamespacemanager.

Thanks

Varun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XPath expression should work like:

`/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/srv:GetNewGUIDResponse/srv:GetNewGUIDResult/text()`

You would need to declare the namespace prefixes. I don't know what API your are using, but you need to declare the following namespace prefixes to make the above expression work for you:

soap -> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
srv -> http://bank.co.com/Service/2011_01/Service

If you don't want to declare namespaces and are using an XPath 2.0 processor you could also do the following (however not recommended!)

`/s:Envelope/s:Body/*[namespace-uri()='http://bank.co.com/Service/2011_01/Service' and local-name()='GetNewGUIDResponse']/*[namespace-uri()='http://bank.co.com/Service/2011_01/Service' and local-name()='GetNewGUIDResult']`

Comment: Thanks. But what is this svr?. I am using xpath and xml classes from Microsoft (using System.XML.XPath).

Comment: I cannot modify the xml file containing the SOAP message.

Comment: you don't have to change the SOAP message. You can name the namespace prefix whatever you like in your XPath (naming it the same as in the XML document is not a "solution"). You need to bind prefixes to namespace URIs using your XPath API.

Comment: Thanks man ! This worked perfectly. Gotta need to learn this stuff. Thanks for your time.